# How do I read value from this array?

Tags: php, arrays

i have this print array in php

```
print_r($user['data_gender'])
```

if the user gender is Man it will display

```
Array ( [1] => Man ) 1
```

if the user gender is Woman it will display

```
Array ( [2] => Woman ) 1
```

i want to check [1] and [2] inside if statement

```
if($user['data_gender']==1) { do something; }

if($user['data_gender']==2) { do something; }
```

what i should do to get only 1 or 2 from this array

Comment: try `$user['data_gender'][1] == 1` and `$user['data_gender'][2] == 2`

Comment: try this if(key($user['data_gender'] == 1)){ //do somthing }

Comment: Yes meet , Thats it , It works!

Comment: Thank you so please give me vote for answer.I posted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this to fetch key of array

```
if(key($user['data_gender'] == 1)){ 
   //do somthing 
}
```

Comment: You should replace the '1' with constants, so that the intention of the conditional is clear for better code quality really. Otherwise when he comes back to it down the line he'll have to spend 5 minutes deciphering what '1' gender is. Other than that, this solution should work for the guys needs. ^^

Comment: i dont know how that happened , may be an mistake

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

To build on @meet's answer. *You should avoid magic strings/numbers* by that I mean you should avoid doing something like

`if (key($user['data_gender'] == 1) { ... }`

Instead do something like:

```
define('MALE', 1);
define('FEMALE', 2);

$gender = key($user['data_gender']);

if ($gender === MALE) { ... }
if ($gender === FEMALE) { ... }
```

That way your code will be clean, and more readable. Any one looking over the code will not have to guess that 1 is Male, and 2 is female.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer --  Most IDEs nowadays will show definitions on hover.  Guessing what a hard coded number "means" is so 2002 :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$user['data_gender'][1]` and `$user['data_gender'][2]` to get both values..!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if($user["data_gender"][1]=="Man") { /* do something */ }
if($user["data_gender"][2]=="Woman") { /* do something */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

let gender be an array  like this

```
gender = {
          [0] => menn,
          [1] => women
        }   

if($gender[0]== 'men') 
{ 
   $men = array('1'=>'men');
   print_r($men);

}

if($gender[1] == 'women') 
{ 
  $women = array('2'=>'women');
  print_r($women);

}
```